# How to access the iOS NSMeasurementFormatter through ionic

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, nsmeasurementformatter

I am using ionic framework and am trying to access the iPhone measurement format settings (Fahrenheit/Celsius, Metric/US/GB, Calendar type, etc) programmatically. After some research, however, I am stuck and can't really find how to do this.

I have seen that there is a plugin called [cordova-plugin-device](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-device). However, this seems to only provide hardware-related (or similar) information. I need to read OS-related information.

After some further research, I found the [NSMeasurementFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmeasurementformatter) class, but I can't find any way of accessing this from my angular code. I guess that there really is no easy way of accessing this information from nodejs.

The only alternative I see is to write a custom swift/objective-c plugin for nodejs. However, I would first like to know if there is any other way.